# Angular delay, pause and restart where it stopped

Tags: angular

I'm starting with angular and I try to make a scenario that displays messages with a delay and the ability to pause to wait for a response based on the message.

I managed to display the message but the functionality to pause, wait for the answer and restart or the scenario was stopped gives me more trouble than I thought.

I thought I might use Observable or Promise, but I'm not familiar with these features and the doc did not help too much.

If you could tell me how to do it or show me a similar example I would be more than happy.

Here is the code that just displays the message in a basic way.

scenario.ts

```
import {Message} from "./message";

export class Scenario {
  id: number;
  messages: Array<Message>;
}
```

message.ts

```
export class Message {
  id: number;
  message: string;
  delay: number;
  wait: boolean;
  type: string;
}
```

mock-scenario.ts

```
import {Scenario} from "./scenario";

export const SCENARIOS: Scenario[] = [
  {
    id      : 1,
    messages: [
      {id: 1, message: 'Message 1', delay: 5, wait: false, type: ''},
      {id: 2, message: 'Message 2', delay: 5, wait: false, type: ''},
      {id: 3, message: 'Message 3', delay: 5, wait: true, type: 'text'},
      {id: 4, message: 'Message 4', delay: 5, wait: true, type: 'text'},
      {id: 5, message: 'Message 5', delay: 5, wait: true, type: 'date'},
      {id: 6, message: 'Message 6', delay: 5, wait: true, type: 'email'},
      {id: 7, message: 'Message 7', delay: 5, wait: false, type: ''},
      {id: 8, message: 'Message 8', delay: 5, wait: true, type: 'text'},
      {id: 9, message: 'Message 9', delay: 5, wait: true, type: 'tel'}
    ]
  }
];
```

ApiTchatLibService.ts

```
getScenarios(): Observable<Scenario[]> {
    return of(SCENARIOS);
}

getScenario(id: number): Observable<Scenario> {
    return of(SCENARIOS.find(scenario => scenario.id === id));
}

getMessages(id: number): Observable<Message[]> {
    return of(SCENARIOS.find(scenario => scenario.id === id).messages);
}
```

ApiTchatLibComponent.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiTchatLibService} from "./api-tchat-lib.service";
import {Message} from "./message";

@Component({
  selector: 'atl-api-tchat-lib',
  template: `
    <p *ngFor="let message of messages" data-id="{{message.id}}">{{message.message}}</p>
  `,
  styles  : []
})
export class ApiTchatLibComponent implements OnInit {

  messages: Array<Message> = [];
  isWaiting: boolean = false;

  constructor(private apiTchatLibService: ApiTchatLibService) {
  }

  getMessages() {
    this.apiTchatLibService.getMessages(1).subscribe(messages => {
        from(messages).pipe(
            concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(
                delay(item.delay * 1000)
            ))
        ).subscribe((r) => {
            this.messages.push(r);
        });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMessages();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this via rxjs easily.

Sample code block

```
from([ { delay: 1000, message: 'A'} , { delay: 2000 , message: 'B'}, { delay: 3000 , message: 'C'} ]).pipe(
  concatMap( item => of(item).pipe( delay( item.delay ) )) 
).subscribe((r) => {
  console.log(r.message);
});
```

code for delaying

```
import { concatMap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';

    getMessages() {
        this.apiTchatLibService.getMessages(1).subscribe(messages => {


       from(messages).pipe(
          concatMap( item => of(item).pipe( delay( item.delay ) )) 
       ).subscribe((r) => {
         this.messages.push(r.message)
       });

     }
```

here we are creating an observable with delay.
concatMap will help you to queue the messages.

Code for start/pause : you can take objects till wait and remaining you can move to an array.

```
import { concatMap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';

class YourClass {
  nextIteration = [];
  messages = [];

  getMessages() {
    this.apiTchatLibService.getMessages(1).subscribe(messages => {
      from(this.start(messages))
        .pipe(concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(item.delay))))
        .subscribe(r => {
          this.messages.push(r.message);
        });
    });
  }

  getNextList(messages) {
    this.nextIteration = [];
    let flag = true;
    let obsMessages = [];
    for (let message of messages) {
      if (flag) {
        obsMessages = [...obsMessages, message];
      } else {
        this.nextIteration = [...this.nextIteration, message];
      }
      if (message.wait) {
        flag = false;
      }
    }
    return obsMessages;
  }

  start(messages) {
    from(this.getNextList(messages))
      .pipe(concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(item.delay))))
      .subscribe(r => {
        console.log(r.message);
      });
  }

  resume() {
    this.start(this.nextIteration);
  }

}


<button (click)="resume()">Start</button>
```

Comment: Thx your code work fine and I updated my post, but how should I pause and resume the observable ?

Comment: which scenario do you want to do pause and resume?

Comment: the message has a wait value set to true or false, and when the value is true, I want the loop to pause, for example, waiting for a click to restart where it was.

Comment: Share your data

Comment: I edited with the mock data of scenario that contain the messages

Answer (score 1):

@rijin suggest nice way to delay, I would avoid nested subscribe.

```
getMessages() {


  this.apiTchatLibService
  .getMessages(1)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(messages => from(messages).pipe(delay(message => message.delay)))
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.messages.push(message);
  });
}
```

if you want to pause/resume, you need to pass resume$ stream into this method. When you  need to resume just put event into resume$ stream.

```
getMessages() {
  this.apiTchatLibService.getMessages(1).pipe(
    concatMap(messages => from(messages).pipe(
       delayWhen(message => message.wait ? this.resume$ : timer(item.delay))
    )
  ).subscribe((r) => {
   this.messages.push(r.message)
  });
}
```

Comment: sorry for the time due to Christmas, your solution seems nice but I start with Angular and I do not understand too much what I have to do with resume$, could you put a little more in your example?